# Spring Boot tests. Initilize database programatically

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I develope a WebApp using Spring Boot. I need to make integration tests with database. I have a problem in database initilization. I know it is possible to prepare database with [initilazion scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html). And I do it partially. But some records have type of BLOB and it is annoying to initilize it by the script. So I'm trying to init this records programatically from `@Test` method using `CrudRepository` implementations from ApplicationContext (that are encapsulated in PersistenceService).

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DatabaseSetup(MyTest.DATASET)
@DatabaseTearDown(type = DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL, value = { MyTest.DATASET })
@DirtiesContext
public class MyTest {
    protected static final String DATASET = "classpath:dbunit/customer.xml";

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private PersistenceService persistenceService;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(false)
    public void afterGroupDeleteCrlShouldContainsAllCertificates() throws Exception {

        prepareDatabase(persistenceService);

        restTemplate.delete("/customer/");
    }
```

But marking of `@Test` method by `@Transactional` is the reason of deadlock when I'm calling `restTemplate.delete()` because there is uncommited transaction.

So I'm trying to commit transaction manually adding after calling of `prepareDatabase(persistenceService)` this snippet:

```
if (TestTransaction.isActive()) {
    TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
    TestTransaction.end();
}
```

This snippet fixes deadlock but generate SQLException after test execution

```
java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
```

I'm sure it is common task. But I don't know how to resolve it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm missing some parts, but how about putting the prepareDatabase into a @Before method in your test.

```
@Before
public void setupDatabaseForEachTest(){
  prepareDatabase(persistenceService);
}
```

I think that will allow your @Test to be @Transactional and give you the desired results.

Comment: It will not transactional method because Spring's TransactionalTestExecutionListener will manage transaction only for @Test methods